# Pandas grouping two columns as master column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe with datetime index:

```
>df

                     DEtoDK    DKtoDE  
datetime                           
2021-01-01 00:00:00  2500.0    2500.0
2021-01-01 01:00:00  2500.0    2500.0
2021-01-01 02:00:00  2500.0    2500.0
```

however, I don't like how it looks like and it restricts me calling two column values together (for example I want to call `DEtoDK` and `DKtoDE` together). Therefore I would like to group two columns `DEtoDK` and `DKtoDE` together into a master column `A`.

**How can I do that?**

Expected Outcome:

```
>df
                     A                   
                     DEtoDK    DKtoDE
datetime                           
2021-01-01 00:00:00  2500.0    2500.0
2021-01-01 01:00:00  2500.0    2500.0
2021-01-01 02:00:00  2500.0    2500.0
```

EDIT:

It can be done easily by Multi-Column by tuples via [How to do Multi-Column from_tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835508/how-to-do-multi-column-from-tuples) , however if I don't have tuples is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use integer division by helper `np.arange` by lenght of columns by `2` and then convert integers to letter s by `chr` and `ord` functions, last pass to [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
a = [chr(ord('A') + x) for x in np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 2]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, df.columns])
print (df)
                           A                 B         
                    A_DEtoDK A_DKtoDE B_DEtoDK B_DKtoDE
datetime                                               
2021-01-01 00:00:00   2500.0   2500.0    500.0    500.0
2021-01-01 01:00:00   2500.0   2500.0    500.0    500.0
2021-01-01 02:00:00   2500.0   2500.0    500.0    500.0
```

Comment: the `'_'` was just for visualisation. I don't really have that in my dataframe.

Comment: @oakca - hmmm, so it means need split by first letter and all another letters?

Comment: Imagine every 2 column is a group, and I want to set a master column name for each 2 columns. More easily imagine I have only 2 columns and I need to set 1 master column for both of these columns

Comment: @oakca - It is possibe numbers like `0,0,1,1,2,2..` ?

Comment: I would prefer a string instead of numbers, updated question @jezrael